# Confusion about return keyword in programming with JS example

Tags: javascript

I am new to programming and was learning JS. The keyword I encountered is the `return` keyword. Let's look at this example:

```
let number = (num1, num2) => {
  return num1 + num2;
}

let result = number(5,6);
```

The question is, is it true that we use the `return` keyword in programming to reuse the value that we want to return from a function, so, basically, the `return` keyword is useful when we want to achieve the "reuse"?

Comment: No - not really.  When you call a function, you basically "stop what you're doing" and "step into" that function.  At some point, you stop executing that function and go back to the statement after your function call.  That point is your `return`.  A "return" may optionally occur *BEFORE* the last statement in the function.  A "return" may also optionally pass a value (e.g. `return num1 + num2`) back to the caller.  Q: Make sense?

Comment: I would say it is more the function which enables code reusability. Sure, `return` plays a part in this, but so do other aspects of the function such as its parameters and body. The main purpose of return is to pass a value from within the function back to the original calling method

Comment: @NickParsons, so, when a given value is returned to the function caller, then we can reuse that returned value in other places Right? That is why return is used in functions

Comment: @Sukich well, yes. But I wouldn't say "reuse" is the correct word. I think just "use" sums up the behaviour. When you return, the value is given to the function caller, where you can then _use_ that value in multiple places (which I guess you could call reusing the value). However, you can just use the returned value in one location, for instance `if(myMethod()) {...}`, in this example, `myMethod()` returns `true` or `false`. Here we are just using the value which it returns to decide whether or not to execute the code in the if block. So returning isn't always about reusing a value

Comment: @NickParsons, Nick can I imagine that when we use e.g if(myMethod()) {...} and when myMethod returns either true or false. Is it true that behind the scenes myMethod is kinda replaced by its return value. That is, "if(myMethod()) {...}" becomes, if it returns, say, true, if(true){...}. I hope you got my point)))

Comment: @NickParsons, or if you look at the example I provided above. let result = number(5,6); when number function returns 11 Is it true that behind the scenes 11 will replace "number(5,6)". And ultimately we will have such code let result = 11

Comment: @Sukich yes, that is exactly right!

Answer (score 1):

basically return is used in function in order to stop the execution of the function, where return keyword is found the execution goes back to the line from where function is called.
If specified, a given value is returned to the function caller.

Comment: Depending on the language more than 1 value can be returned and I cannot think of one but I am guessing there are languages that do not stop execution at return but when the function scope ends.

Comment: Maybe you are right but I'm explaining the basic concept of return in JS as mentioned in question.